# Some Weird getString Bug

Tags: java, file-io

I have a class set to return a string like so:

```
package TextRPG;

public class File {

    static String file;

    public static void setFile(String fileLocation) {
        file = fileLocation;
    }

    public static String getFile(){
        return file;
    }
}
```

But when i try to call it like so:
`PrintWriter save = new PrintWriter(File.getFile());`
I get an Error. What am I doing wrong?
EDIT, the netbeans error is :
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getFile()
  location: class File

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you set the file before getting it? And please follow Java NAming Conventions. Your varaibles should be `file` and not `File`. And if it's the name of the file, better name it as `fileName`.

Comment: Also, `File` is a pre-defined class in Java. You should not name your class with that name. Further, I don't see any reason to create such a class. Why are you doing something like that?

Comment: A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these situations, a variable will be chosen in preference to a type, and a type will be chosen in preference to a package. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html)

Comment: Please use standard naming conventions: variable names start with lowercase letter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shot yourself in the foot because you are ignoring the Java naming conventions.

Variable names should start with a lowercase letter.  Thus:

```
package textrpg;

public class File {
    static String file;

    public static void setFile(String fileLocation) {
        file = fileLocation;
    }

    public static String getFile(){
        return file;
    }
}
```

The java compiler doesn't care about this ... but your foot shot happened because you declared a field called `File` in a class called `File`, and Java's rules for disambiguating the name collision came up with a strange answer.

(If you included the compiler error message, it would be easier to explain ...)

---

There are a couple of other problems with this class:

- The is very non-OO code.  You have a static field and static methods for getting and setting it.  This kind of thing is a bit "icky" ... and will lead to problems if you need to reuse the code in another context, or implement unit tests, etcetera.
- You are using the same name as a well-known standard class (`java.io.File`).  This could lead to problems later on if some other class in your application needs to use both `java.io.File` and `textrpg.File`.
- You are also ignoring the convention about how to form a package name that is designed to avoid package name collisions.

---

Before you write more code, I strongly recommend that you read the [Sun Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).  And unless you have a *really really* good reason not to, follow them.  ("I couldn't be bothered" is NOT a good reason, IMO.)

---

Ah.  So the compilation error is in this:

```
PrintWriter save = new PrintWriter(File.getFile());
```

and it is saying that it can't find a method called `getFile()` in `File`.

Without seeing the rest of that class, I can't be sure.  However, I *suspect* that you are importing `java.io.*` ... and THAT means that the `File` in the code snippet will be referring to `java.io.File` ... which doesn't have a `getFile()` method!

Comment: EDIT, the netbeans error is : cannot find symbol symbol: method getFile() location: class File. The Compiler error is WAAY too long